# git not found by vscode in Windows 10

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I tried many suggestions and git is still not shown on the source control panel in vscode in windows 10:

[image]

My git is installed as the following:

```
C:\Users\name>git --version
git version 2.23.0.windows.1

C:\Users\name>where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Git is enabled in my vscode:

[image]

Git path is set as shown above in settings.json:

[image]

[image]

The @builtin search in Extensions also shows that the built-in Git is enabled:

[image]

What I shall do to get that little Git icon shown in Source Control, as shown below?

[image]

Comment: You don't have a folder open that is a git repo.

Comment: Yes, as you suggested once I open a local folder in vscode containing a repo cloned from Github, git function becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

As @jhpratt suggested:

1. open a local folder containing a repo cloned from Github:

[image]

[image]

2. Git will show up on source control panel:

[image]

3. Changes made in a file will be identified:

[image]

4. Stage and commit the change:

[image]

5. ... and push the committed changes:

[image]

6. The committed changes are updated in Github:

[image]